# Why does dojo use a span instead of an anchor tag for its close dialog icon, 'X'?

Tags: dojo, dialog, anchor

I would expect the 'X' in the top right corner in a dojo dialog to be a link. Is there a reason it is coded as a span?

Answer (score 0):

The `dojo`'s 'x' is not a link, it's a button.

Comment: Ok, in that case, why is it not coded as a <button>? The reason I ask is span is non-semantic, so wondering if there is a specific reason it is being used here?

Comment: Button may have had quirks in old IE, IIRC, but Dijit uses [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria) to give non-semantic markup meaning.